# Matplotlib fill_between behaving incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using maptplotlib to plot points. I want to fill area between two points from x-axis. the two pints in x-axis are p1 = 1643237118161 and p2 = 1643237119999. When I try to plot the graph, the fill area is a very thin line, but if I increase the p2 point by just 1 to 1643237120000, the fill area is bigger and can be seen better.
My question is why if I use p2 = 1643237119999, I get a very thin line? How can this be fixed?

```
# Code for plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df_gpsprobe.timestamp, df_gpsprobe.speed, 'ro-')
ax.fill_between(df_gpsprobe.timestamp, df_gpsprobe.speed, 0, 
                where = (df_gpsprobe.timestamp >= 1643237118161) & (df_gpsprobe.timestamp <= 1643237119999), color = 'g')
plt.xlabel('timestamp (ms)')
plt.ylabel('speed (m/s)')
plt.show()
```

p2 = 1643237119999
[image]

p2 = 1643237120000
[image]

Comment: The time series data you are dealing with is in milliseconds, isn't it because p2=16432312000 reaches the next millisecond break?

Comment: Yes, the time stamp is a Unix milliseconds timestamp. But why would fill_between work only between the break points? It should ideally fill color between any two points that I give. Isn't it?

Comment: It's because you use the `where=` argument, it works only on data coordinates. Create `x` and `y1` by yourself and you'll be fine. See [the doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html).

Comment: I created x and y1 my self, but it still did not solve the issue.